# Interal server error when using multipart/form-data Express/KrakenJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, kraken.js

Having an issue with doing a post request using multipart/form-data. Any post request that is made just returns Error: Forbidden. This is the console output

```
Error:Forbidden
127.0.0.1 - - [Sat, 12 Apr 2014 20:08:33 GMT] "POST /addComic HTTP/1.1" 500 666     "http://localhost:8000/admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,                     like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
```

In my index.js file I have included all the middleware that I need

```
server.use(express.urlencoded());
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.multipart());
```

In my controller I am just printing the file details to the console.

```
app.post('/addComic', auth.isAdmin, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files.comicFile);
});
```

Here is the form

```
<form action="/addComic" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" id="_csrf" name="_csrf" value="{_csrf}"/>
    <div class="form-group">    
         <input type="file" class="form-control"  id="comicFile" name="comicFile">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add comic">
 </form>
```

I am stumped as to why I am getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same problem, but this may help....

I'm having a similar problem with Kraken.js. `text/plain` forms work just fine but `multipart/form-data` isn't working. The error I get is `CSRF token mismatch` so sounds like it's similar (I've received the `Error: Forbidden` message when I've _csrf problems in the past). What I've noticed (by putting a breakpoint in the lusca code) is that the `req.body` object is empty, even though I can see it being posted from the client.

I solved this by reverting to an older version of the installed node_modules I had (I started experiencing the problem after doing an `npm install` on a new working directory and thus getting newer version of dependencies down. I suspect the problem was in the lusca package.. when I reverted to "~0.1.1" (as defined in the `package.json` for `kraken-js`) it started working again.

Comment: Sorry, should have added that to get this version of lusca I used the following version of kraken in 'package.json': '"kraken-js": "0.7.0"'